# Error: == irace == 'digits' (--digits) must be within [1,15] within MLR package

Tags: r, mlr

I'm trying to run this code found in the MLR tutorial, I get the following error:

> Error: == irace == 'digits' (--digits) must be within [1,15].

I already tried the function `convertParamSetToIrace` but it hasn't worked.

The following is the code:

```
library(mlr)
data(iris)
iris.task = makeClassifTask(id = "tutorial", data = iris, target = "Species")
base.learners = list(
  makeLearner("classif.ksvm"),
  makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
)
lrn = makeModelMultiplexer(base.learners)
ps = makeModelMultiplexerParamSet(lrn,
makeNumericParam("sigma", lower = -12, upper = 12, trafo =function(x) 2^x),
makeIntegerParam("ntree", lower = 1L, upper = 500L)
)
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2L)
ctrl = makeTuneControlIrace(maxExperiments = 200L)
res = tuneParams(lrn, iris.task, rdesc, par.set = ps, control =
                   ctrl, show.info = TRUE)
print(head(as.data.frame(res$opt.path)))
```

Comment: Hi @Mel, could you provide your `ps` object ?

Comment: And please don't cross-post in GH and SO next time.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the code.